# state value is undefined on Redirect

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, router

I need to pass data to another page using react redirect method, but I'm getting undefined value of state.

Form Component:
onSubmit I'm getting values of state through console.log but these values are not passing to Show component

```
class RegisterForm extends React.Component{

    //constructor here

    // handleInputChange function here

    submit(){
        
        console.log(this.state);
        const data = this.state;
        return <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/show',
            state: {data: data},
        }}
        />
        }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                        <br /><br />
                        <h3>Register Form</h3><br />
                        
                        <form
                        action="show"
                        > 
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label>First Name :</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label>Last Name :</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>this.submit()}>Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )  
    }
}

export default RegisterForm;
```

`props.location.state // undefined`

can you help me?

Comment: You may need to share a lot more code than this. Is the receiving component correctly rendered by a `Route` or wrapped in the `withRouter` HOC?

Comment: check now, i've added Show component

Comment: Have you tried ```this.props.location.state.data```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: Is the `submit` function returning renderable JSX? That doesn't look like it should work at all. Can you include a good snippet of that component? Namely its render function and anything related to that callback.

Comment: i've added component  ... check now

Comment: constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            first_name:null,
            last_name:null,
            email:null,
            city:null,
            address:null,
            gender:null,
            hobbies:[]
        }

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);

    }

Comment: I just notice that form is not calling submit function ... it redirects to show page because ive used action ="show"
can you telll me why submit function is not calling

Answer (score 1):

[Form action - Attribute for form submission](http://Attributes_for_form_submission)

> The URL that processes the form submission.

Question

> It redirects to show page because I've used `action="show"` can you
> tell me why submit function is not calling

The `submit` function isn't linked to anything in the UI. The form has a button of type "submit", so when clicked the default form actions are taken, i.e. the form is submitted and tries to go to the page specified by the action. React *doesn't* quite work in this way.

Since the button type is already "submit" you can simply replace the action prop with the `onSubmit` callback.

```
<form onSubmit={submit}> ...
```

Now that the `submit` callback handler is being invoked you'll also want to not take the default submit action on the form (likely a page reload). Returning JSX won't work here either, it won't ever get rendered. In order to do the redirect you'll need to do this using the history object from the Router/Route. This assumes `RegisterForm` is rendered directly as `component` or `render` prop of a `Route` or has been decorated with the `withRouter` Higher Order Component.

```
submit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log(this.state);

  const data = this.state;
  const { history } = this.props;

  history.replace({
    pathname: '/show',
    state: { data },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Function Components insted of class components,
Class components are too old, ***Life becomes too much easier with function components***, and ***react hook***s. I suggest you to go though **react fucntion components** and **react hooks**.

here I converted your class component into the function component with some hooks,

in submit method, just use `history.push('/show',state)`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const RegisterForm = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        first_name: "",
        last_name: "",
    });
    const history = useHistory();

    const handleInputChange = (key) => (e) => {
        let value = e.target.value;
        setState((s) => ({ ...s, [key]: value }));
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        history.push("/show", state);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <h3>Register Form</h3>
                    <br />

                    <div className="form-row">
                        <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label>First Name :</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="first_name"
                                value={state.first_name}
                                onChange={handleInputChange("first_name")}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label>Last Name :</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="last_name"
                                value={state.last_name}
                                onChange={handleInputChange("last_name")}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-row">
                        <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <button
                                className="btn btn-primary"
                                onClick={handleSubmit}
                            >
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default RegisterForm;
```

Now, In the component at `/show` route,
you can use,

```
 import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
 ....
 ....

// inside the Component,
let location = useLocation();

console.log(location); 
console.log(location.state); // you can see, your state is available here...
```

that's it!

let me know if you found some difficulties here.

***good luck ;)***

Comment: Complete rewrite to fix a simple issue, seems a bit excessive/extreme.

Comment: @DrewReese Yaa, I know. I just want to suggest him to use function components, insted of class components.